# Flutter/Dart DNS resolving timeout

Tags: http, dart

```dart
http.get('https://my-domain.com');
```

> I/flutter ( 5767): SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'my-domain.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

If I add `.timeout(Duration(seconds: 30))` to future, it applied to connection+dns+request send+response

I only want to set timeout for DNS resolving

Comment: Have the same issue, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46645